# java showSettings implementation/source of information

Tags: java

Java -XshowSettings dump the information such as VM setting. Where in the box/system this information configured or what is the source of the setting? Is there any property file ?

> java -XshowSettings:all

Comment: Have you checked something like https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/launcher/LauncherHelper.java#L152?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information comes from various sources; e.g. command line options, environment variables, values derived from the result of syscalls, default values hard-wired into the JVM executable, and so on.

> Is there any property file ?

There are some system properties that are defined by property files in the `$JAVA_HOME/cfg` tree, but the majority of the properties and other settings come from other places.